# How to structure views in bigquery for efficient access management

Tags: google-bigquery, access-control

In BigQuery you give users/roles (or authorized views) access on dataset-level and not views/table-level. The challenge I want to address is how to manage access control in bigquery when I have hundreds of tables and views and many different roles/departments that should have access to both views shared across all departments and views only for a particular role/department?

Example: let's say I have a source dataset with source tables A->D and three views for each table exposing different fields based on sensitivity of data 1->3. Also, I have three roles (Blue, Green, Red). If I could manage access on table-level it would look like this:

View: roles

- A1: Blue, Red
- A2: Red
- A3: Red
- B1: Blue, Green, Red
- B2: Green, Red
- B3: Red
- C1: Green, Red
- C2: Green, Red
- C3: Red
- D1: Red
- D2: Red
- D3: Red

Given these requirements, I can't create datasets based only on sensitivity (1-3) or source (A-D) and manage access based on that. The only solution I can see that meet this is generating a dataset per role. This could be done manually if the number of roles and views are few, but when managing 10+ roles and 50+ views it becomes more challenging.

The only solution I can come up with is a CI/CD setup (cloud build) with file/s defining datasets (i.e. roles), dependencies and DDL-statement/s. Letting a script/program iterate through the file/s and generate views and give access (authorized view) to source.
Example file:

```
{"roles":["crm_analyst", "admin", "customer_service_agent"],
"ddl":"CREATE VIEW `myproject.'{role}'.newview` AS SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM myproject.mydataset.myview",
"dependencies":"myproject.mydataset.myview"}
```

How do other companies solve this? There are large banks that have migrated to bigquery that must have loads of departments and different sensitivity of data sets.

Comment: Wondering what are good solutions outside of BigQuery to model this. Maybe that could drive a feature request

Comment: @felipehoffa I guess most companies put the ACL in the application layer that connects to BigQuery, i.e. BI-tools. But I want users to be able to connect to BigQuery with whatever tool (tableau, data studio, collab, etc.) they prefer and still be certain that they only can access data that they have permission to. That’s the reason for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a python script that reads view definitions from json-files and then generate datasets and views and give correct access rights. The solution is a bit rough and could make use of dependency mapping (when a view queries another view) instead of the current solution iterating views until all views are generated or the script can't generate anymore views (broken dependencies). The script generates two datasets per group, one with READER (suffix '_ro') and one with WRITER (suffix '_rw') to make sure that views generated by data team can't be modified and at the same time give a sandbox for the group. The group should be an e-mail group and the name of datasets will be the local-part of the email address. The script is executed by google cloud build and triggered by a push to our github repo.

Example view definition (path: views/view_test.json)

```
{
    "groups":["developers@datahem.org", "analysts@datahem.org"],
    "sql":"SELECT * FROM `{project}.shared_views.test_view`"
}
```

Generates the following datasets (access) and views:

```
analysts_ro (analysts@datahem.org:READER):
- view_test

analysts_rw (analysts@datahem.org:WRITER):
(empty)

developers_ro (developers@datahem.org:READER):
- view_test

developers_rw (developers@datahem.org:WRITER):
(empty)

shared_views (analysts_ro.view_test:None, developers_ro.view_test:None):
- test_view
```

I made the [python script](https://github.com/mhlabs/datahem.viewer) available on github as open source as part of [datahem](https://github.com/mhlabs/datahem), feel free to clone, improve and use for your own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Share datasets with groups instead of roles. Have a group for each "role"; red, green and blue. Create datasets having only the views. Share the source dataset.tables with the views.

- RED_DATASET:
  shared: RED_GROUP
  VIEWS:
  A1-A3,B1-B3,C1-C3,D1-D3
- BLUE_DATASET:
  shared: BLUE_GROUP
  VIEWS:
  A1,B1
- GREEN_DATASET:
  shared: GREEN_GROUP
  VIEWS:
  B1-B2,C1-C2

Notice the B1 view will have three copies of it (one in each "view_dataset") and be define with the by the same query.

This is the [recommended practice](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#create_a_separate_dataset_to_store_your_view) regarding access control for view.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, you confirm my thoughts about the structure of datasets, tables and views. But how do you build those? Manually or automated in a CI/CD setup? I’m also thinking about setting up a sandbox dataset for each role/group to let users create and experiment with views in that one.

Comment: You can use the BigQuery API or the client libraries to do automated.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set up row-level access and put all views in the same dataset.

Mockup an access_control table (user, usergroups) for example purpose:

```
SELECT 'userA@datahem.org' as user_name, ['developer','analyst'] as user_groups
UNION ALL
SELECT 'userB@datahem.org' as user_name, ['developer'] as user_groups
```

And create a view that has row-level access control by adding a static column with array of user_groups and join with the access_control "table" where at least one of the current user's groups match the allowed_groups:

```
SELECT c.* EXCEPT(allowed_groups) FROM (
  SELECT OrderReference, Date, ['developer', 'analyst'] AS allowed_groups 
  FROM `project.dataset.orders`) as c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_name, user_group 
  FROM  `project.access.access_control`, UNNEST(user_groups) as user_group 
  WHERE SESSION_USER() = user_name) g
ON g.user_group IN UNNEST(c.allowed_groups)
```

It is a nice solution, however it exposes all views to a user even if the user doesn't have access to it. Also, the user will be able to run queries against a view he/she doesn't have access to (generating cost) but won't get any results back. From a usability perspective (only showing views a user has access to) we chose the solution marked above.